# Print to usb Printer (ql700) from python code

Tags: python, usb, printing

I am somehow new to python coding,
I am writing a program that creates barcodes and then prints them to a thermal Label Printer, I currently own a Brother QL700, drivers and all working.

The printer is located in /dev/usb/lp0
I have searched for days for any help on the Web of how to print from python but somehow without success or even an idea of where to start, so far I am able to create the barcode and save it as a image png or svg, but haven't been able to print even letters so far! Any help or guidance of where to start would be great!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tried following this? http://www.howtogeek.com/169679/how-to-add-a-printer-to-your-raspberry-pi-or-other-linux-computer/

Comment: Was not exact, but i managed to print by using Cups, If you like, post it as an answer so that I can mark it!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution: [Python package to control Brother QL label printers](https://github.com/pklaus/brother_ql). This solution allows to perform printing without drivers for the raspberry and requires no additional opragramowania. You can easily to print directly to the printer.

Comment: That looks like a useful solution. The bit about adding oneself to the `lp` group is important for accessing USB printers

Comment: @scruss I'm confused. Aren't `/dev/lpX` devices created by the printer driver? If the OP bypasses the driver, there's no reason to be in `lp` group.

Comment: No, they're most often created by udev. CUPS just grabs them if you have that port assigned to a CUPS-controlled printer. I work with cheap generic thermal printers quite a bit, and /dev/usb/lp0 appears whether I use CUPS or not. Adding oneself to the `lp` group just means you can write to it without `sudo`.